# Python USB devices

Tags: python, keyboard, usb

I want a python script that should block the normal usage of a particular USB keyboard, not all and then use the input sent by that keyboard in the python program further to process it

I want that keyboard should not function normally but shoudl only give the input data to python program

Answer (score 0):

You can use the python module [keyboard](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/). `Keyboard` allows detecting key presses, and simulating them, and should solve your problem pretty quickly. To make sure that input can't be used in the keyboard, we can use the `block_key()` function. However, we also need to detect key presses. I used `pynput` to do that. Here's a snippet of code:

```
import keyboard
from pynput import keyboard as keys

def onPress(key):
    #process whatever key was pressed

for key in range(150):
    keyboard.block_key(key) #blocks all keys on keyboard

with keys.Listener(on_press=onPress) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: for a particular keyboard

Comment: Did you test this code? (I think it works for a usb keyboard still)